# `cairo_image_surface_create_from_png` returns "out of memory", but I have enough memory

Tags: lua, x11, cairo, awesome-wm, lgi

*Note: I am writing my own window manager that is similar to AwesomeWM in that it will be written in C, and have a lua api for customisation.*

#### The problem I'm facing is with this code:

```lua
local bg_img = lgi.cairo.ImageSurface.create_from_png("path_to_image.png")
print(bg_img.status) -- This prints "NO_MEMORY"

-- this is part of the window manager api, but I think you can still make out what's going on
local s = tsoil.create(screen_width, screen_height)
s.cr:rectangle(0, 0, screen_width, screen_height)
s.cr:set_source_surface(bg_img)
s.cr:fill()

tsoil.set_as_wallpaper(s)
```

This code prints out "NO_MEMORY" for some reason. I don't think this should happen, since the image is only about 600kb of memory.

I also tried loading in a much smaller image (26kb in size), and that worked.

I also tried running my window manager with Xephyr, and also directly with `startx`, but that didn't make my code with the larger image work. I don't know how to fix this.

**EDIT: I also tried this in awesome-wm and it also fails. Again, I don't know why.**

**EDIT2: I also tried to rewrite this code in C, and it still gives the same error:**

```
    // only the code that gives this error, for the sake of brevity
    cairo_surface_t *img = cairo_image_surface_create_from_png(path);
    // this prints "out of memory"
    printf("%s\n", cairo_status_to_string(cairo_surface_status(img)));
```

Comment: Can you load that image with something else than cairo? What does `file` identify the image it? Can you perhaps upload the image? A random guess is that this is some other kind of error that just gets coerced into "out of memory" somewhere.

Comment: @UliSchlachter You were right, check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

#### Nevermind, I found the answer.

I tried loading a ".jpg" image with the cairo `...from_png` function, which is my fault.

However, this is not entirely my fault. Cairo should have an error return value that should clearly signify that the file exists, but is not a PNG.

Comment: You actually made me fix cairo for this: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/cairo/cairo/-/merge_requests/524 Hopefully, this means that eventually in the future one actually gets `CAIRO_STATUS_PNG_ERROR` / "error occurred in libpng while reading from or writing to a PNG file".